# CMake for compiling gtkmm4 : error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, gtkmm4

I'm trying to convert the command-line compilation and building to a CMake one for gtkmm-4 in Ubuntu 22.10

```
 raphy@raohy:~/gtkmm-prj$ cmake -B build
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 12.3.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "1.8.1") 
-- Checking for module 'gtkmm-4.0'
--   Found gtkmm-4.0, version 4.10.0
-- Checking for module 'giomm-2.68'
--   Found giomm-2.68, version 2.76.0
-- Configuring done (0.4s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/raphy/gtkmm-prj/build

raphy@raohy:~/gtkmm-prj$ cmake --build build
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/basic.dir/src/basic.cc.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable basic
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/basic.dir/src/basic.cc.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN4Glib7ustringD1Ev'
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglibmm-2.68.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/basic.dir/build.make:97: basic] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/basic.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

But the command-line compilation and building goes fine:

```
raphy@raohy:~/gtkmm-prj$ 
raphy@raohy:~/gtkmm-prj$ g++ src/basic.cc -o basic `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-4.0`
raphy@raohy:~/gtkmm-prj$ ./basic
```

This is my `CMakeLists.txt` file :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(tutorial01 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(gtkmm-4.0 REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET  gtkmm-4.0)
pkg_check_modules(giomm-2.68 REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET giomm-2.68)


add_executable(basic src/basic.cc)

target_compile_options(basic PUBLIC ${gtkmm-4.0_CFLAGS_OTHER} ${giomm-2.68})
target_include_directories(basic PUBLIC ${gtkmm-4.0_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${giomm-2.68_INCLUDE_DIRS})



target_link_libraries(basic PUBLIC
    gtkmm-4.0
    giomm-2.68
)
```

What's wrong with CMakeLists.txt file? How to make it work?

Comment: The IMPORTED targets in your case are `PkgConfig::gtkmm-4.0` and `PkgConfig::giomm-2.68`, not the ones `gtkmm-4.0` and `giomm-2.68` which you are using in `target_link_libraries` call. Also, when use IMPORTED targets, variables `_CFLAGS_OTHER` and `_INCLUDE_DIRS` are not needed: a linkage with a target automatically gives all those properties.

Comment: Thank you @Tsyvarev. Those were my mistakes. If you write that as an Answer, I can flag it as correct. Thank you again